# Как создать оконное приложение под mac os на c++?

Tags: c++, mac

Только начал изучение языка c++, пишу программки в консоли. Хочу узнать можно ли под mac os написать оконное приложение и с помощью какой библиотеки? Понимаю, что обычно пишут на objective-c, но так как нужно изучить c++, нужен альтернативный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например на qt https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos.html. вот еще хороший гайд: https://www.ics.com/blog/getting-started-qt-and-qt-creator-macos